# Why am I not allowed to enter my future employer?

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

I already signed my contract and I would like to add my new employer to my CV, but the UI blocks me since the start date is in the future.

Can you change that?

Comment: Congratulations on your new job!

Comment: Your contract may still be canceled or you may not actually start your job for a lot of other reasons. Why not simply wait a few weeks/months until you have *actually* worked for the company? :)

Comment: In that case I can edit my profile again. However I don't expect that and that didn't happen for me yet. An alternative reason is that I want to remove my current employer from my profile. I'm not interested in advertising them.

Comment: Because then you're as functional as LinkedIn @deceze, which doesn't allow me to add accepted papers with a publishing date ahead of the current one. And surely that's a comparison they may wish to avoid. :p

Comment: *deceze, 2025 - ?: CEO @ Google Inc. (aspirational)* – I can see how this gets tricky fast… :)

Comment: *Bart, 1976 - ? CEO & Founder of Apple Inc.* Lying on your CV is always possible, and the consequences are yours.

Comment: OMG the CEO of Apple writes on my question :-D

Comment: Is this the place to ask for a free new MacBook Pro?

Comment: they are giving you time to change your mind

Comment: The current rule is simple; once you allow future dates, you'll get into wishy-washy territory. Surely it would be absolute nonsense to accept *all* future dates, like the year 2025. And so the back and forth begins… *how far* in the future to you allow the date to be…? A week? A month? Two months? Surely not three months?! Three months? OK, three months. But not FOUR, right?! *Right?!?!* – I think that's the best argument to keep it as is…

Comment: @deceze You mean, I bought this expensive time machine and I can't even use it to improve my CV??

Comment: @Cody Since it's a time machine, you can always return it, even years later… I just hope you kept the receipt .

Comment: @deceze Well it makes sense to block the user to select a future job, but why should it be impossible to enter a job in the near future let say 3 or 6 month.

Comment: Again… define "near future". Either the limit is so close that somebody *will* get bitten by it eventually, or it's so far out as to be useless. At least the current one isn't entirely arbitrary, easy to reason about and simple.

Comment: @deceze What about allowing us to enter a future job, but showing it just in the preset. So when I enter it now for march it will been shown in march. Fair enough in my opinion.

Comment: That should be a given I think. If any future jobs will be accepted as input at all, they will only be shown from that date. I think the question is more about input validation and whether to accept *uncertain* future information at all.

Answer (score 11):

Technically you don't work there yet, albeit that you have a contract. Having simple validation to stop users inputting invalid values is correct in my opinion. Fair enough your job may start in the next week say, but if the validation was removed then any date in the future could be added and if you give users the ability to input invalid data, then they will.

I'd also imagine there are queries run relating to the jobs side of the site that might make an assumption that all dates will be in the past, but that's just a guess. As a result, I believe removing this validation will likely not be a simple front end change.

Comment: E.g. on XING I can enter that job

Comment: @rekire never heard of them but `XING != SO`; each will select their own validation methods. I understand yours is a use case that's valid, but your case is maybe valid and useful for <1% of users (sorry random figure). Removing the validation will undoubtedly result in the underlying data that powers Jobs becoming more invalid over time, which would outweigh your justification.

Comment: Sure but SO is better then XING and that is why I am wondering why SO doesn't support it.

Comment: `SO > XING`... I don't think that's justification enough to implement such a change to the validation, but complimenting the site might help your cause ;)